# Return value must be of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse,

Tags: laravel

I'm following the Lucid architecture in my application and facing an error in my Laravel application's LoginFeature class. When I try to execute the handle() method, I receive the following error message:

"App\Services\Client\Features\LoginFeature::handle(): Return value must be of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse, Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch returned"

This error occurs in the file "D:\cosduk.net\server\app\Services\Client\Features\LoginFeature.php" on line 18.

Here is the relevant code snippet from LoginFeature.php:

```
class LoginFeature extends Feature
{
    protected string $guard = 'user';

    public function handle(): JsonResponse
    {
        try {
            return $this->run(new UserLoginJob($this->guard));
        }
        catch (InvalidInputException $exception) {
            return $this->run(new ValidationErrorsJob([
                'email' => 'These credentials do not match our records',
            ]));
        }


    }
}
```

I'm expecting the handle() method to return a Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse object, but it seems to be returning an instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch instead.

How can I resolve this error and ensure that the handle() method returns the correct response type?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: That might indicate `UserLoginJob` is queueable so will run asynchronously (i.e. in the background in the queue and outside the request/response lifecycle)

Comment: Hmm, i’m think, run() function must return JsonResponse

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using what looks like an abandoned project to base your laravel project around some opinionated "architecture"

Comment: Also just browsing the docs none of the feature classes have an explicit return. Simply remove that `: JsonResponse`.

Comment: And I still wouldn't recommend using it. It's all just another "look at how slim my controllers are" project, where none of the logic is simplified, it's just swept under the rug.

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with handle() method with JsonResponse type. YOu will always have to return JsonResponse  type data. I think your handling method is not doing that. So , for solving this issue simply remove return type from your method and modify code like below

```
class LoginFeature extends Feature
{
    protected string $guard = 'user';

    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            return $this->run(new UserLoginJob($this->guard));
        }
        catch (InvalidInputException $exception) {
            return $this->run(new ValidationErrorsJob([
                'email' => 'These credentials do not match our records',
            ]));
        }


    }
}
```

[image]